# replace variable value and store it in new variable

Tags: perl

I have below code to replace the variable value and store it in new variable and leave the original variable intact.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$hdisk="hdisk361";
($newdisk) = ($hdisk =~ s/(hdisk\D*)(\d+)/(($1 eq "hdiskpower"?"prw":"dsk").$2)/ei);
print "hdisk: $hdisk"."\n";
print "newdisk: $newdisk"."\n";
```

It gives this output:

```
hdisk: dsk361
newdisk: 1
```

I want the output like this:

```
hdisk: hdisk361
newdisk: dsk361
```

Please help me to fix this code?

Comment: Please *always* include `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of your code. It will catch many errors, in fact often so many that you don't even have to post here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or a bit shorter:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$hdisk="hdisk361";
($newdisk = $hdisk) =~ s/(hdisk\D*)(\d+)/(($1 eq "hdiskpower"?"prw":"dsk").$2)/ei;
```

Otherwise, as you saw, you get 1, meaning a successful operation. In the code you provided you captured the return value instead of the result.

But don't forget to use `use strict` and `use warnings` ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$hdisk = "hdisk361"
$newdisk = $hdisk;
$newdisk =~ s/(hdisk\D*)(\d+)/(($1 eq "hdiskpower"?"prw":"dsk").$2/
```

Comment: Very straightforward, but it needs another semicolon or two.

Answer (score 3):

The substitution `s///` works by side-effect.  Its return value is hardly ever what you want.  You especially don't want to use `s` here, when you seem not to want `$hdisk` to change.

Capture the pieces of `$hdisk` with `m` instead of `s`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $hdisk="hdisk361"; 
my ($word, $number) = $hdisk =~ m/(hdisk\D*)(\d+)/i;
my $newdisk = ($word eq "hdiskpower"?"prw":"dsk").$number; 
print "hdisk: $hdisk"."\n";
print "newdisk: $newdisk"."\n";
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is this approach preferable to what wickie79 or I suggested? Or is it just an equally valid alternative?

Comment: @canavanin, I've found that naming my captures (here, `$word` and `$number` instead of `$1` and `$2`) is a good way to help readers of my code understand what I'm trying to do.  That could be colleagues, or it could be myself in six months time.  As for splitting the capturing and the assignment into two statements, I know there's a clever way to do it in a single statement, but by the time I've remembered how to do it (there are pitfalls, as sfgroups just noticed), I could have confidently typed the two statements and gone on to do something else.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on it a bit, you've got a point there! You've also taught me something in your post, so thanks for that, too.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a bit superflous, but anyway, if you are using a fairly modern version of Perl (5.13+), you could have the original code working by just adding the r flag:

```
use 5.013;
($newdisk) = ($hdisk =~ s/(hdisk\D*)(\d+)/(($1 eq "hdiskpower"?"prw":"dsk").$2)/rei);
```

You could even let go of the parens:

```
use 5.013;
my $newdisk = $hdisk =~ s/(hdisk\D*)(\d+)/(($1 eq "hdiskpower"?"prw":"dsk").$2)/rei;
```

You can read more on the `/r` flag  at [Use the /r substitution flag to work on a copy](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/09/use-the-r-substitution-flag-to-work-on-a-copy/).

Comment: @Hugmeier Thanks for mentioning this feature, and besides that: thanks for the link to that very helpful webpage!